# Restricting deep linking functionality in android when user is accessing the mobile website

Tags: android, deep-linking

I am trying to implement deep linking features in android. I want to restrict the deep linking features so that it only gets triggered when clicking on any external links as in through Google search or shared url, but it should not trigger while user is accessing the mobile website of the domain.  I have followed all the steps as mentioned in the android official docs.  So currently as soon as the mapped URL is clicked the deep linking functionality is getting triggered.  Can anyone please help me on this?

//Intent filter

```
 <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="www.example.com"
                    android:path="/en"
                    android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

success-scenario:if user clicks on https://www.example.com/en from google search it should open the app,but if user clicks on "https://www.example.com/en" link while browsing the website https://www.example.com it should not take me to the app.

Comment: Could you post a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Jason:Updated my question with a code snippet

Answer (score 0):

By removing the path="/en" from your data inside the intent-filter maybe it help.

- This way the user can interact with the website as much as they want;
- and if they interact with a shared link via chat, for example, it would trigger the App Links.